# How to build a proper json response

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to build a php script that will return a properly formatted json response, current my json response will come with backslash or the inner objects comes quoted.

```
class myObject
{
    public $property1;
    public $property2;
    public $property3;
    public $property4;
}

$MyObjects = array();

$results = DB::table('sometable')->get();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $MyObject = new myObject;
    $MyObject->property1 = $result->col_1;
    $MyObject->property2 = $result->col_2;
    $MyObject->property3 = $result->col_3;
    //$MyObjects[] = $MyObject;
    array_push($MyObjects, $MyObject);
}

var_dump($MyObjects);
echo json_encode($MyObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try below code. It will return proper response.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
$response=array();

$query="select * from studmaster";
$result=$con->query($query);

if($result->num_rows>0)
{
    $response["student"]=array();
    while($rows=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {
        $student=array();
        $student["studid"]=$rows["studid"];
        $student["studname"]=$rows["studname"];
        $student["studmobno"]=$rows["studmobno"];
        array_push($response ["student"],$student);
    }

    $response["status"]=1;
    $response["message"]="Data Exist";
}
else
{
    $response["status"]=0;
    $response["message"]="Data Does Not Exist";
}
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Where did you figure out `studid`, `studname` or even `$student`? What is the relation of code you posted vs what's asked in OP? Where did you explain your code? How exactly are you solving *return a properly formatted json response, current my json response will come with backslash or the inner objects comes quoted.*?

Comment: **Simple and Easy Code to send Data through Json Using Php.** Nice answer

Answer (score 0):

To remove the backslash you can write-

```
echo json_encode($MyObjects, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```